# Windows 7, tint the entire screen programmatically using .NET?

Tags: .net, screen

In Windows 7, can I give the entire screen a tint programmatically using .NET?

To clarify, I don't want to just add a color tint to a window, I want to add a tint to the entire monitor / desktop area.

Is there anyway to do this in .NET?

Like my screen would look like this if I added a blue tint.
I think what I want is just a transform of the video output, I just don't know where to start?
Flux does this I think...

[image]

Comment: My thought is, you can do anything. Just use the right Windows API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx